# MailChimp Api 2.0 Late Execution

Tags: mailchimp

I have a procedure working with API 2.0 that register a subscriber on a list and then to a static segment under the same list. 
The list registration is done is real time, but the registration under the static segment require a while (more then 1h) before I can see the added subscriber.
Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

MailChimp has a (good) caching mechanism. So immediate changes may not show in the dashboard.
Please check the ["Best practice" guidelines for integrators or folks developing around the MailChimp API](https://apidocs.mailchimp.com/api/faq/#faq5).